# Why does this show zero

Tags: c

here is the code. why is the answer zero?

//Write a program that reads the temperature in Fahrenheit and displays it in Celsius.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
float fah,cel;
printf("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit\n");
scanf("%f",&fah);
cel=5/9*(fah-32);
printf("The temperature in Celsius is %3f",cel);
return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0OOk.png)

Comment: Because `5/9` is an integer division resulting in `0`.

Comment: `cel=5.0/9.0*(fah-32);`

Comment: oh so i have to make 5.00 or 9.00. thanks

Comment: Welcome! In your future questions, it is better to post text as text, not as *pictures* of text. It's just as easy to copy/paste the terminal output, and it enables readers to copy/paste too. With a picture of text, it's not so easy.